# Plane parallel to the base of a triangular pyramid

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, 3d, solid-geometry

A triangular pyramid $ABCD$ is given. A plane parallel to the plane $(ABC)$ intersects $DA,DB$ and $DC$ at $A_1,B_1$ and $C_1,$ respectively. Show that $\dfrac{DA_1}{DA}=\dfrac{DB_1}{DB}=\dfrac{DC_1}{DC}$.
[image]
I think I am supposed to use Thales theorem for the given equality but I am not sure how to begin the solution. Thank you in advance!

Comment: I would say take $\triangle DAB$ and $\triangle DA_1B_1$ and establish $DA / DA_1 = DB / DB_1$. You can follow the same for next face of the pyramid.

Comment: @MathLover, it seems that $A_1B_1\parallel AB$ and $B_1C_1\parallel BC$. If we can show that, by the Thales theorem we can say $\dfrac{DA_1}{DA}=\dfrac{DB_1}{DB}=\dfrac{DC_1}{DC}$. I didn't understand what you meant.

Comment: Yes. As $AB$ and $A_1B_1$ are coplanar and that they can never meet (as they are also in parallel planes) makes them parallel by definition of parallel lines. So by Triangle Proportionality Theorem, $\dfrac{DA_1}{DA}=\dfrac{DB_1}{DB}$. Then take $\triangle DBC$ and $\triangle DB_1C_1$ and show $\dfrac{DB_1}{DB}=\dfrac{DC_1}{DC}$.

Comment: You mean $AB$ and $A_1B_1$ are not coplanar?

Comment: They are coplanar (both are in the plane that has $\triangle DAB$)

Comment: @MathLover, But is it necessary for them to be coplanar (for them to be parallel) in general?

Comment: Yes for them to be parallel lines, they must be coplanar and never meet

Comment: Can two non-coplanar lines be parallel? Or two lines cannot be non-coplanar?

Comment: If they are parallel, there must be a plane that has both lines. Two lines can surely be non-coplanar.

Comment: Show that If a plane intersects two parallel planes, then the lines of intersection are parallel then apply Thales.

Comment: @MathLover, I don't see why $AB$ and $A_1B_1$ can't be parallel. What will happen if we let $A_1B_1\cap AB=K$? How will we get a contradiction? I find it easier in solid geometry to suppose that something is true and then show it cannot be with a contradiction.

Comment: @Katherine I do not follow you. All my arguments was to prove that they are parallel. We cannot continue elaborate discussions in comments but I am happy to move this to chat and explain further there.

Comment: @MathLover, I edited my comment. I think it's clear now.

Comment: @MathLover, let me show you what I mean. Let's suppose $A_1B_1\cap AB=K$. Then $K$ must lie on both lines $A_1B_1$ and $AB:$ 
$$
K\in A_1B_1, A_1B_1\in(A_1B_1C_1) \Rightarrow K\in(A_1B_1C_1)
\\ K\in AB, AB\in(ABC)\Rightarrow K\in(ABC).
$$ So we got that $K\in(A_1B_1C_1),(ABC)$ but they are parellel so $A_1B_1\cap AB=\emptyset$.

Comment: That is correct. So that shows both lines are parallel. My earlier comment - As $AB$ and $A_1B_1$ are _coplanar_ and that they can never meet (as they are _also_ in _parallel_ planes) makes them _parallel_ by definition of parallel lines.

Answer (score 1):

Consider a side of the pyramid, say $\triangle ABD$. $\frac{DA_1}{DA}=\frac{DB_1}{DB}$ then follows from [intercept theorems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intercept_theorem).

$\hspace{6cm}$[image]